# Проблемы с расширениями в 63ей версии хрома

Tags: chrome-extension

При подключении внутри расширения файла скрипта почему-то этот файл подключается дважды. К тому же почему-то перестал работать атрибут в манифесте "run_at" "document_end" и теперь расширение стартует одновременно с загрузкой страницы.

Файл манифеста:

```js
{
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "version": "1.0",
 "name": "Test",
 "background": {},
 "content_scripts":[{
  "matches": ["*"],
  "js": ["js/jquery.js","js/connect.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
 }],
 "browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Test"
 },
 "web_accessible_resources" : [
  "js/test.js"
 ]
}
```

Connect.js

```js
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('js/test.js'), 
 function(data) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  script.innerHTML = data;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
 }
);
```

Test.js

```js
console.log('test');
```

Comment: Укажите `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]` вместо `*`

Comment: Это мне не то чтобы поможет. В самом расширении там весьма конкретный урл. Или его тоже можно как-то иначе написать?

Answer (score 0):

Собака оказалась зарыта в слишком старой версии jquery. Кто бы мог подумать, что хром такая привереда?

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать более подробный ответ?

Comment: У меня в расширении было подключено jQuery. Оказывается версия у него была аж 1 с копейками при актуальной ныне 3й. Немного странно, что старая версия начала так адово себя вести с хромом от 63й версии, но пусть так :D